# How to copy one field to another using visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Hi I would like to know how can we copy one custom field to another using visualforce pages or javascript.

I had created the following code

```
   <apex:page standardcontroller="Product_and_Services__c">

<apex:form >
<font size="20" color="green">
<apex:outputText value="Total Price : "/>
       <apex:outputText id="total" value="{0, number, $###,###}">
            <apex:param value="{!Product_and_Services__c.Annual_Price_of_Screening__c + Product_and_Services__c.TotalAlaCarteScreenings__c + Product_and_Services__c.Total_APR_Screening_Record__c - ((Product_and_Services__c.Annual_Price_of_Screening__c + Product_and_Services__c.TotalAlaCarteScreenings__c  + Product_and_Services__c.Total_APR_Screening_Record__c) * (Product_and_Services__c.Discount__c/100)) }"/>
                </apex:outputText>
 </font>




  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

I am trying to find a way to copy the Total  Price field into a custom field in Salesforce. PLease let me know if there is a way using javascript or visualforce pages ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your need?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to copy the Total Price field into a custom field in Salesforce. PLease let me know if there is a way using javascript or visualforce pages ?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to get this value (that you presently compute using a Visualforce expression) into a custom field on the same object is to add a formula field containing the expression:

```
Annual_Price_of_Screening__c
+ TotalAlaCarteScreenings__c
+ Total_APR_Screening_Record__c
- ((Annual_Price_of_Screening__c + TotalAlaCarteScreenings__c + Total_APR_Screening_Record__c) * (Discount__c/100))
```

and just present that formula field in your page:

```
<apex:param value="{!NewFormulaField__c}"/>
```

This approach has the benefit of making the (presumably important) value available in other contexts such as list views or reports or email templates. It also ensures that the value is always consistent with the current values of the contributing values.

Comment: It does change the field to read-only, however. Though you could use the same formula in a field update.

Comment: Thanks Keith, however I used a visulforce page because the value exceed more than 5000 characters in the formula field

Comment: @DominicSeb You could do the calc in e.g. a trigger. Typically I've done something just in the UI I've regretted it later.